# Scrollview disabling for container view

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have two container views inside a scroll view. I want to disable horizontal scrolling of one of the container view.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the scrollviews delegate and prevent the horizontal scrolling with:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  if scrollView.contentOffset.x != 0 {
    scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
  }
}
```